# Unity internal compiler error with custom dll

Tags: c#, c++, plugins, dll, unity-game-engine

I spent some hours trying solutions I found online but nothing worked so here's my question for Stackoverflowers.

I made a small plugin for Unity and imported the dll into my project folder. It works fine when I launch the game within the editor but if I try to compile I get the following:

```
Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)

  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespace (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.GlobalRootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.LoadReferences () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What I did so far:

- my dll is in the Plugins folder in Assets
- tried to place the dll (also) in the project root
- tried with and without namespaces
- set .NET 2.0 in Unity

And by the way, it works fine in Unity Editor so it should be pretty clear that I made it right as I followed the instructions in the official Plugins making guide.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Wasn't sure.. the dll as all the plugins for Unity is made in C++

Answer (score 2):

When I deleted the dll from the *Plugins* folder while leaving just a copy of it in the project's root folder, **it worked**.

So in this case the solution is to **leave the dll just in the project's root folder** and nowhere else.

I'm not sure why though, so part of the question is still open.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was setting the target platform lower(from 4.5 to 3.5).
As suggested here:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ideas-reflectiontypeloadexception-the-classes-in-the-module-cannot-be-loaded.230389/

Answer (score 1):

The thing I needed to do was change the API compatibility level from .NET Subset 2.0 to .NET 2.0. Suddenly all was fine. Probably the threading task was doing some problems.

Please see [reference](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ideas-reflectiontypeloadexception-the-classes-in-the-module-cannot-be-loaded.230389/)

Answer (score 0):

For what platform are you trying to compile the script?

If you're doing it for iOS make sure that you don't have any events declared inside the DLL.

I had problems with this and I ended up removing them.