# Native Android library in Unity throws DllNotFound exception

Tags: android, c++, unity-game-engine, mono, native

I have written a chess library in C++ and I have compiled it for Windows (32-bit and 64-bit) and Android (x86 and armebi-v7).

My Windows build works completely correct, But when I build it for Android and when I run the game, I receive the following exception on my `adb logcat -s Unity` :

```
11-23 16:39:37.278 22335 22352 I Unity   : DllNotFoundException: MatinChess
11-23 16:39:37.278 22335 22352 I Unity   :   at (wrapper managed-to-native) MatinChess.Net.ExternMethods:Initialize ()
11-23 16:39:37.278 22335 22352 I Unity   :   at MatinChess.Net.MatinChess..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
11-23 16:39:37.278 22335 22352 I Unity   :   at Model.Awake () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

And when I unzip my apk file I have:

```
lib
|_ armeabi-v7a
|  |_ libmain.so
|  |_ libMatinChess.so
|  |_ libmono.so
|  |_ libunity.so
|_ x86
   |_ libmain.so
   |_ libMatinChess.so
   |_ libmono.so
   |_ libunity.so
```

### Here are my settings and scripts:

Based on [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html), I have created `Plugins` folder in my **Assets** and placed my libraries like this:

```
Plugins
|_ Android
|  |_ libs
|     |_ armeabi-v7a
|     |  |_ libMatinChess.so
|     |_ x86
|        |_ libMatinChess.so
|_ x64
|  |_ MatinChess.dll
|_ x86
   |_ MatinChess.dll
```

And I got sure that the **Platform Settings** in my **Inspector** is configured correctly.

I have used my library in my scripts and based on [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#library-names) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html), instead of using `libMatinChess.so` for Android, I have not used `lib` at the beggining and `.so` at the end. So it is like this:

```
class ExternMethods
{
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    const string dll = "MatinChess";
#else
    const string dll = "MatinChess.dll";
#endif

    [DllImport(dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static PlayState CheckState();

    [DllImport(dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static void Initialize();

    //
    // other extern methods
    //
}
```

So when I build my Unity game for Windows, it works correctly. In order to make it work in Editor, I have followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33124250/3511987) and I have written the folowing script:

```
public class Model : MonoBehaviour
{    
    void Awake()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR_32
        var dllPath = Application.dataPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Plugins" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "x32";
#elif UNITY_EDITOR_64
        var dllPath = Application.dataPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Plugins" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "x64";
#else // Player
        var dllPath = Application.dataPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Plugins";
#endif
        var currentPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        if (currentPath != null && currentPath.Contains(dllPath) == false)
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", currentPath + Path.PathSeparator + dllPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    }
}
```

So it works on Unity Editor as well.

Comment: Why you are configuring .dll file for Android as you already have .so file?

Comment: @PravinD I want to say that my Windows build which uses .dll configuration works ok but Android which has .so configuration does not. And inform you about the differences of my configurations.

Comment: What version of Unity3D are you using?

Comment: @zwcloud the version is 5.4.1f1 Personal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you are actually exporting a valid .so file with the proper symbols.

Also check that you have included all library dependencies of your `libMatinChess.so` which may include your C runtime at times. Try linking statically with the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

The method `MatinChess.Net.ExternMethods.Initialize` may be called before `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",...)`, which leads to a DllNotFoundException.

Try printing a log message before you call `MatinChess.Net.ExternMethods.Initialize` and `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`. Then you can inspect the calling order of these methods.

Add if that's the cause, moving `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",...)` to the static initializer of `MatinChess.Net.ExternMethods` can possibly solve your problem.

**Edit:**
Try printing the `PATH` after you setting it, the method may failed to set it.

**Edit:**
Just a guess.. the android shared lib searching path should be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of `PATH`. Try setting that instead. I'm not sure if Unity3D has handled this.

**Edit:**
Not including all the library dependencies aside your `libMatinChess.so` is a possible cause. Some infomation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058898/loading-shared-libs-that-depend-on-other-shared-libs).

The above are all I can think of now.

Comment: Nope. I call Initialize after that.

Comment: Have you checked the logs on the android platform? Is it in the correct order?

Comment: I have tested all you two edits. I also found my .so inside my adb shell but still dllnotfound exception.

Comment: That's all I can think of now, sorry.